# Infinite loading for a ReactJS app despite me having lazy loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Soo. I am getting an infinite loading screen when I start my react app. Eventually after waiting like 2 minutes it says Error code: Out of Memory. I tried lazy loading with seperate components in seperate files and it stills does the same thing. If you want to see the code, https://github.com/SupaSibs/social-media-network/tree/Supa-Branch/client/website/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `<Posts />` tag in the Posts class which means you call this class in itself. Which creates a infinite loop. You just need to rename your posts component and import it so it is not the same name as the Posts root class.